# Modifying LastWriteTime directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, windows-7-x64, propertychanged

I would like to change a folder lastWriteTime without modify a lastWriteTime of files which are in this directory.

I have been trying this:

```
$a = Get-Date "02/09/2013 4:59 PM"
$d = "C:\Users\user\Documents\CV"
$d.LastWriteTime = $a
```

but it's didn't working because `d` has not a LastWriteTime property.
There is any way to change this property? I have to modified lastTimeWrite property only "CV" directory - files in "CV" shouldn't be touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to cast it to `[system.io.directoryinfo]`

```
$a = Get-Date "02/09/2013 4:59 PM"
$d = [system.io.directoryinfo]"C:\Users\user\Documents\CV"
$d.LastWriteTime = $a
```

or using `get-item` cmdlet

```
$a = Get-Date "02/09/2013 4:59 PM"
$d = get-item C:\Users\user\Documents\CV
$d.LastWriteTime = $a
```

Comment: @mjolinor I see it like a bug.. I've tryed this is v2.0, I'm curious to test it in v3.0, now I can't...

Comment: @mjolinor On native V2 works like a charm, later I'll test it on a V3 and give here feed back

Comment: @CB Not sure what changed, but I closed the session I was using, opened a new one, and now it works.  Being in the directory I was trying to change might have been messing with it.

Comment: @mjolinor Can be! On v2 works also for the directory being changed by.

Comment: @mjolinor fyi, I use v4 and used (get-item $filename).lastwritetime=(get-date "some date") without any issues

Comment: Not sure what was happeing, but I can't reproduce it now, so just ignore that.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function Touch-File
#Touches a file or folder if the file does not exist it creates a new empty    file
    {
    $file = $args[0]
    $date = $args[1]

    if($file -eq $null) {
        throw "No filename supplied"
    }

    if($date -eq $null) {
        throw "No date supplied"
    }

    if(Test-Path $file)
    {
    #Optionally select the date stamp you want to update

         (Get-Item $file).LastWriteTime = $date
         (Get-Item $file).CreationTime = $date
         (Get-Item $file).LastAccessTime =$date
     }
     else
    {
         echo $null > $file
    }
}
```